# Cleanse phone number data in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I want to cleanse my phone number data. The formula

`=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(E2,"(",""),")",""),"-","")," ",""),".","")+0`

does part of the job.  But I also want to incorporate an `IF()` statement so, if the length is less than 11 and there is no 0 at the start, add a leading 0. Numbers can be landline or mobile but I think the main issue will be missing 0 and spaces. See the data sample below:

7523698745
 7896541236
 1235552207
 07841 256321
 01235552204
 7845 213698
 07845632158
 01235552204

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your question, it appears that you are trying to go through a phone number with different special characters throughout and pull the integers of the phone number. For example the number `(123) 456-7890` should return `01234567890`.

Try the below User Defined Function ([Explanation of UDF's](http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/user-defined-function.html))

```
Function PARSEPHONENO(number As String) 'Number is the selected cell

Application.Volatile 'The formula will recalculate itself
Dim answer As String 'The value returned from the function
Dim i As Integer 'Used to loop through each character of the selected 'number' String

     For i = 1 To Len(number) 'For each character of the cell from 1 to the lenght of the string
           If IsNumeric(Mid(number, i, 1)) Then answer = answer & Mid(number, i, 1) 'If the value if numberic then add it to the answer
     Next i 'Next Character

     If Len(answer) < 11 And Left(answer, 1) <> "0" Then answer = "0" & answer 'If the answer is less than 11 digits, add a zero to the beginning of the cell

PARSEPHONENO = answer 'Return the answer
End Function
```

Note: The formula will return a String value of the numerical digits to the leading 0 will display in the cell.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

With your current output in column **A**, in **B1** enter:

```
=IF(AND(LEN(A1)<11,LEFT(A1,1)<>"0"),"0" & A1,A1)
```

and copy downward:

[image]

Comment: Many thanks, dude, bandersnatch and Gary, all 3 do the job but in different ways.

Answer (score 0):

Your current formula forces the result to be a number by adding `0`.  Because the result *is* a number, Excel will strip any leading zeros, so it's pointless to check for one.  This is shown in Columns B:E of the table below.

Column A is your sample data, B is the result of your formula, D is the result of your formula without the `+0` at the end.  Columns C,E,G and I show the first character of the cell to their left using `=LEFT(cell,1)`.

[image]

There are a couple of tricks you can use to have Excel display leading zeros. Column F is the same as Column B except with a custom format of `"0"#`.  This *displays* leading zeros, even though they aren't really there as shown by Column G.

Column H uses this formula

`=IF(LEN(B2)=10,0&B2,B2)`

which gives a text result, but has real leading zeros.

So how you decide to handle this issue depends on whether you need to have your data stored as numbers or if they can be text.